# Since flutter 1.9 : how to run flutter app in a browser ? Flutter run -d chrome not working

Tags: ubuntu, flutter, flutter-web

Since flutter 1.9 flutter_web is merged inside flutter. I'm trying to run the initial flutter app in a chrome browser but it fails. OS is ubuntu 19.04

The command I used with success: 
flutter upgrade

flutter create test_1_9

cd test_1_9

flutter run

The command not working:

flutter run -d chrome

=> No devices found with name or id matching 'chrome'

I tried with google-chrome as device name with same result

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.10.2-pre.38, on Linux, locale fr_FR.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.10.2-pre.38 at /home/rbarbe/programes/flutter
    • Framework revision e6ae95c4ce (il y a 18 heures), 2019-09-11 07:46:57 -0700
    • Engine revision 7ea9884ab0
    • Dart version 2.5.0 (build 2.5.0-dev.4.0 be66176534)


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/rbarbe/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /home/rbarbe/programes/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at /home/rbarbe/programes/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 33.3.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.1)
    • IntelliJ at /home/rbarbe/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/191.6183.87
    • Flutter plugin version 35.2.2
    • Dart plugin version 191.6183.88

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.2)
    • IntelliJ at /home/rbarbe/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/192.6603.28
    • Flutter plugin version 39.0.5
    • Dart plugin version 192.6603.23

[✓] VS Code (version 1.38.0)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.4.1

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • CLT L29 • WCR0218315003400 • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: I have followed this steps and it's working! https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web

Comment: You're right @SharadPaghadal, documentation has bee updated since this morning. I didn't know about the following command : flutter config --enable-web

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Have you enabled web support by `flutter config --enable-web` ?

[image]

> Got Reference from this [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web)

Comment: Even after running `flutter config --enable-web` still m getting error as `No devices found with name or id matching 'chrome'`.

Comment: which channel you are on? Please update the flutter once `flutter upgrade`

Comment: @DhavalKansara Make sure you are on stable channel

Comment: It was not working on the stable channel. After I took check out for the master branch I'll found chrome in flutter devices.

Answer (score 33):

For these people whose `chrome` still cannot be detected even after `flutter config --enable-web`.You should  check if your flutter in appropriate branch ,to list all branches, use:

> flutter channel

output may looks like this:

```
Flutter channels:  
   beta  
   dev  
   master  
*  stable
```

item with asterisk prefix indicates which branch you are in.To switch to master, try:

> flutter channel master

after that, your `flutter doctor` can list `chrome`device.

Comment: fantastic, i was searching solution for 2 hours before reaching this out. 100% works!

Answer (score 25):

https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web

```
$ flutter channel master
$ flutter upgrade
$ flutter config --enable-web

$ flutter devices  //downloads sky_engine and sdk tools then shows a list of devices including chrome

$ flutter create test_app
$ flutter run -d chrome  //local host will run chrome


>>>>>>>Extras

if you need run in optimized mode and disable security than

flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html --web-browser-flag  "--disable-web-security" 

to compile your code for chrome deployment use

flutter build web --release --web-renderer=html
```

Comment: in visual studio code for windows 10, select the main.dart  file it will give you a run icon on the top right side, letting you run with debug.

Comment: These steps worked for me only that instead of flutter run -d chrome, I used flutter run -d linux for the obvious reason --Linux.

Comment: `flutter run -d chrome` did the magic

Comment: flutter run -d chrome --release --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA=true --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_COMPRESSED=true   (this commands runs the code like you will see when released to production)

Answer (score 13):

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
```

Comment: Thanks, bro. This works in ubuntu 21.10.

Answer (score 5):

In my case - flutter doctor gave me the following output

```
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
```

as on arch, the binary is called google-chrome-stable and/or google-chrome-unstable

```
export CHROME_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
```

was all that was needed to get it working.

Comment: To add to this, all available environment variables are declared here : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/web/chrome.dart. Right now, they are `CHROME_EXECUTABLE` and `EDGE_ENVIRONMENT`.

Comment: This is really helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a server for web and will then be available at a port presumably 8080. If everything is set up correctly you can just:

```
webdev serve
```

otherwise try:

```
   flutter packages pub global run webdev serve
```

Comment: that was prior to 1.9 release, it's now deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to upgrade flutter form the master instead of the stable branch

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu, ensure you are on the master channel by running

*flutter channel master*

Then run

*flutter upgrade*

Allow HTML web rendering be running

*flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html*

Answer (score 0):

Adding chrome to user variables worked for me, I moved chrome to another drive and it was not being identified by flutter.

System properties > Environmental Variables > on user, create new then add:

Variable name :CHROME_EXECUTABLE

Variable Value :D:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe (location of your chrome.exe file)

Answer (score -1):

you need cd to your flutter install workspace, and run:

```
git checkout master
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are trying to develop web Application with dart then my suggestion is to create new Dart Project -> Angular Dart -> After successfully created angular dart -> then open terminal -> type "Webdev serve"